# Isomorphism group between $\mathbb R$ and one of it's propre subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

Is there a  subgroup $H$ of $(\mathbb R,+)$ such that $H \neq  \mathbb R$ and $H \simeq \mathbb R$ as groups?

Comment: yes there is , all supgroups of R are isomorphic to R under addition  operation.

Comment: @Bswan Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you said, but isn't $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ under addition not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+)$?

Comment: yes my bad ! i totally forget about Z , forgive me xD

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Nate's hint is perfect, but in case you're curious about the result but can't get the proof quickly, I'll just tell you: the answer is yes, there are lots of such subgroups (though it is probably very hard to pin one down explicitly).

Comment: You may want to look at this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35970/construction-of-a-proper-uncountable-subgroup-of-mathbbr-without-choice

Comment: @Nate, Slade and Anurag: Thank you very much. Your hint also gave me  an idea about the case of additive groups $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^2$: there is not an isomorphism $f$ between them since $f$ would be an isomorphsim between them as $\mathbb Q-$ vectoriel spaces wich is impossible because they are finite dimension $1$ and $2$ respectively.

Comment: @Bswan Isomorphic groups must have the same cardinality (because an isomorphism is a bijection). $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subgroup but not of the same cardinality.